# Functions that have their second derivatives as a lipschitz function

Tags: numerical-methods, special-functions, examples-counterexamples, continuity

What would be an example of a function that is not $C^3$ on $[0,1]$, but has its second derivative as a Lipschitz function?

Comment: A cubic spline is $C^2$ but has discontinuous, piecewise constant third derivatives.